# I can't upload a gif to a Wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

When I  upload a gif to a post, it shows as a static image on the live site. There is no "full-size" option in the image uploader. I also tried changing the default wordpress option for images. Maybe this is a problem with the theme? I'm using the Perfect Portfolio theme by Rara Theme.

[image: image uploader]

I think it may also be a problem with the settings in the image uploader.

Comment: it's possible that your theme does not support animated GIFs.Did you try another theme with it?

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you using?